# Should I proceed with treating "functions" the same way as "statements" in Antlr4 grammars?

Tags: antlr4

I am using listener to process my grammar, assigning values from the processed input to my internal data structure. I want to move to the next level (for me!) and start processing input like Func(x,y,z) to correspondingly invoke the class members of my internal data structure. Should I proceed it with the same approach, of having EnterFunc/ExitFunc members of the generated Listener and finding out which member I need to call internally or there is other approach? I have a paper copy of "The definite Antrl4 reference"; I will really appreciate pointing me to the right chapter if such method is described in it.
Thanks!